# How to set Tomcat permissions on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: linux, tomcat, systemd

I installed Tomcat on my Ubuntu 18.04.

```
sudo systemctl status tomcat

● tomcat.service - Tomcat 9 servlet container
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-03-23 08:00:51 CET; 25s ago
  Process: 7620 ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/latest/bin/shutdown.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 7586 ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/latest/bin/startup.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Let's taker a deeper look with journalctl -xe. Output:

```
-- Subject: Unit cups-browsed.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit cups-browsed.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
мар 23 07:59:53 miki rsyslogd[1286]:  [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.32.0" x-pid="1286" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] rsyslogd was HUPed
мар 23 08:00:32 miki dbus-daemon[4552]: [session uid=1000 pid=4552] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal' unit='gnome-terminal-server.service' requested by ':1.74' (uid=1000 pid=6386 c
мар 23 08:00:32 miki systemd[4419]: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
-- Subject: Unit UNIT has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit UNIT has begun starting up.
мар 23 08:00:32 miki dbus-daemon[4552]: [session uid=1000 pid=4552] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
мар 23 08:00:32 miki systemd[4419]: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
-- Subject: Unit UNIT has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit UNIT has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
мар 23 08:00:46 miki anacron[1187]: Job `cron.daily' terminated
мар 23 08:00:46 miki anacron[1187]: Normal exit (1 job run)
мар 23 08:00:51 miki sudo[7583]:     miki : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/miki ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl start tomcat
мар 23 08:00:51 miki sudo[7583]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
мар 23 08:00:51 miki systemd[1]: Starting Tomcat 9 servlet container...
-- Subject: Unit tomcat.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit tomcat.service has begun starting up.
мар 23 08:00:51 miki startup.sh[7586]: Existing PID file found during start.
мар 23 08:00:51 miki startup.sh[7586]: Removing/clearing stale PID file.
мар 23 08:00:51 miki startup.sh[7586]: Tomcat started.
мар 23 08:00:51 miki systemd[1]: Started Tomcat 9 servlet container.
-- Subject: Unit tomcat.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit tomcat.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
мар 23 08:00:51 miki sudo[7583]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
мар 23 08:00:51 miki shutdown.sh[7620]: PID file found but either no matching process was found or the current user does not have permission to stop the process. Stop aborted.
мар 23 08:00:51 miki systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
мар 23 08:00:51 miki systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

How to fix this permission problem?

I configured `/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Tomcat 9 servlet container
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat

Environment="JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java"
Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom -Djava.awt.headless=true"

Environment="CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.33"
Environment="CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.33"
Environment="CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.33/temp/tomcat.pid"
Environment="CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC"

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/latest/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/latest/bin/shutdown.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

How to check why no matching process was found or the current user does not have permission to stop the process?

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the whole `/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service`? Remark that Ubuntu 18.04 has an [official tomcat9 package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/tomcat9), which is correctly integrated into the system, so there is not need to use other sources. You can also comment the `ExecStop` line, since the default action (kill the process) shuts down Tomcat 9 in a clean way.

Comment: The user calling `shutdown.sh` should be correct, but the pidfile might be wrong. When the server is up, check if `/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.33/temp/tomcat.pid` contains the correct PID of the **java** process and if you can send signals to it: `sudo -u tomcat kill -0 <process PID> && echo OK || echo Error: $?`.